# Why is CSP reporting a violation for connect-src when the domains are the same and 'self' is allowed?

Tags: content-security-policy

I'm seeing a lot of violation reports like this (100s per day):

```
"csp-report": {
    "document-uri": "https://example.com/en/path",
    "referrer": "https://example.com/en/path",
    "violated-directive": "connect-src",
    "effective-directive": "connect-src",
    "original-policy": "...; connect-src 'self' https://example.net google.com ...etc.",
    "blocked-uri": "https://example.com/",
    "status-code": 0
}
```

I would have thought that 'self' means that 'mydomain.com' is allowed?

Are these valid reports or have I misunderstood the syntax?

Can they be ignored? (or might some functionality of the app then stop working, if they are due to some bug in a browser?) They come from a variety of browsers and OS.

There is only one CSP on the site - this is certain.